# Given a known set of keys, can one determine an optimal hash function for them?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, hash

gperf seems to be one option (if using C or C++), but are there better ones, at least for some situations?  An example application would be in linking code with exceptions.  For the common implementation of exception handling, the linker would need to construct an optimal associative lookup from return addresses (for calls to functions that can generate exceptions) to the address of destroying / finalizing code for the function, for the stack unwind.

Comment: The title sounds more like a math/CS question then a programming one.  Not sure what you are getting at with the body of the question.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes but it's relevant to the languages I tagged, and I also tagged algorithms.  The relevance to exception handling is the relevance to Java and C++.

Comment: What's an *"optimal hash function"*?

Comment: You can of course use gperf with any language. You'll just have to translate the hash to the target language if it isn't C or C++.  Moving it to Java would be easy for example.

Comment: @BaummitAugen zero or minimum collisions, minimal maximum (non-negative) integral result.

Comment: You get such a function by just enumerating all the keys, but I doubt that's what you want. Needs a better definition it seems.

Comment: @WaltK I was about to post as an answer what Baum mit Augen added as a comment. Given a known set of keys, defining a hash function is trivial: for any arbitrary enumeration key1, key2, ..., keyn of the n keys, let the hash function be defined as h(keyk) = k. You get no collisions and there is no wasted space.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the known set of keys beforehand, then build a [trie/keyword tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of the keys. Put a unique index at each words end.

This way, your hash function will never takes more than `O(length_of_the_largest_string)` time. And the memory needed is `O(total_character_in_all_the_strings)`

If you use only the unique prefixes, then you can reduce some time and memory.

Comment: Yes but is there another way that is faster and uses less memory (at execution time).

Comment: @WaltK Can you elaborate which specific method you are suggesting?

Comment: it's an honest question, I have no method to suggest. Modulo, FNV, CRC are I think among the fastest hash functions.  It would be cool if, given a set of keys, you could derive a best polynomial for a CRC hash of them.

Comment: After thinking about it, I agree that a splay tree of some sort is probably the best solution when you are looking up keys that may or may not be in the table.  But if you only look up keys that are known to be in the table (like the example in my question) a "perfect CRC", if such an animal exists generally, might be significantly better.